# How to fix buggy anti-alias font in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

Look this pic:

[image: http://gyazo.com/a6c39d5ebbf18bce55ddf4baf6637bbd.png]

The font looks wrong, it shouldn't have black background with alpha letters, i had no idea what happened to this font system.

The font is Arial, the size is 80 pixel and the anti-alias method is "None"

[image]

The other anti-alias method like crisp, smooth and strong worked very well, but i prefer alias font.

Anyone can help me how to fix this bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1785/text-in-my-photoshop-image-looks-blurry

Comment: can you let us know how you got those separators? and what exactly you are doing here, it's not at all possible that if you chose crisp, smooth and strong they work very well but when you chose "none" it comes with black background?? may be i am wrong but i doubt its not 86px..

Comment: Are you sure it's not just highlighted or a video buffer glitch? What happens when you save the image and re-open it? Does it still look like that? Also, only certain small-type and bitmap fonts are designed for un-AAed rendering. Arial and most fonts look horrible when aliased. I hope you're not doing this sort of thing for a professional project.

Answer (score 0):

Start in 32 bit mode, that should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Posting Ivan's message as an answer, as he left it in a comment.

> I know you have experience of using an anti-alias font, BUT im doing
>   for classic 8 bit videogame fonts
>
> I found a solution, I was using the 64 bit version of Photoshop CS5.
>   It looks fixed and clean using "None" parameters in the 32 bit
>   version.