# PS font does not match HTML font

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, web-fonts

On my mac I use font 'Open Sans' Semibold which translate to:
font-family: "Open Sans";
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 600;
line-height: 16px;

using CSShat plugin.

The result in HTMl doesn't look the same as is PSD (see attached image).

Any ideas please?

[image: left is HTML, right is PS]

Comment: I have no experience with the plugin you're using but seems like one has more character spacing than the other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font (anti)aliasing in Photoshop](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/font-antialiasing-in-photoshop)

Comment: The rendering is always going to look different (as the Q&A Luciano just posted says), PS isn't really meant for laying text... other than that you just have some tracking in the PSD which you don't in the CSS.

Comment: Shouldn't be designing in Photoshop should be designing in the browser. You will never get that finite look unless you make everything image based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `letter-spacing: 1px;` to your ID or class.

```
font-family: "Open Sans";
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 600;
line-height: 16px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
```

The default is `letter-spacing: 0px;`. You can also use  `letter-spacing: 0.25px;` or `letter-spacing: 0.5px;`, etc.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZarEx

Comment: I think you got that the wrong way around... looks like the PSD has positive tracking applied and the CSS has none

Comment: Corrected.  Also added 0.25 and 0.5 to the Codepen example.

Comment: Steve, you nailed it! CSSHat plugin ignores VA value of the font. thanks!